# How does ntpstat work?

Tags: sync, ntp

I have installed ntp on some of the network machines I am working on. When I check ntpstat, I see that it says clocks are synchronized to some ms, usually between 12 and 70 ms.

My questions are:

- How does NTP find out the above values?
- If it knows these values, why doesn't it correct itself?
- Are these values positive or negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does NTP find out the above values?

The NTP protocol allows each computer to calculate the effect of network latency (the time a timstamped packet takes to get from one computer to another) as well as any difference in clock time.

> If it knows these values, why doesn't it correct itself?

It does, but it attempts to do so smoothly, network jitter can make the time differences appear to change when they have not.

> Are these values positive or negative?

They are usually displayed by `ntpq -p`with a - sign when negative.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used `ntpstat` (it's not a standard install on debian/ubuntu) but have used ntp for many years and generally look at the output of `ntpq -nc peer` or `ntpq -np` which probably shows similar information. The `ntpq` output does show positive and negative values.

Basically, if ntp(stat) says it's synchronized (or the output of ntpq flags a server with a '*') then it's as close as it can get but it will continue to try and improve.

A simplified explanation of the operation of NTP is that it regularly send packets to time servers containing a timestamp of the time the local machine thinks it is. The server then adds its timestamp and returns the packet to the local machine. As soon as it arrives, the local machine has a 3rd timestamp, the arrival time. Assuming the packet took the same time to reach the server and return, NTP can work out what the local machine's time was when the server added it's timestamp and hence can calculate a difference and make an adjustment.

Network packets generally take a few tens of milliseconds to reach the server and return. Due to network traffic variations, the outgoing and incoming transit times may not be the same, but there's no way to determine this, hence NTP has to assume they are the same. As a result, NTP can never get closer than a few milliseconds to exact synchronization and will declare synchronization when the send and receive timestamps bracket the server's timestamp.

Even when synchronized, NTP will continue to exchange packets and try to adjust the time to minimize the time differences. It does this by making small adjustments (actually by slightly increasing or decreasing the number of clock 'ticks' in a second) so that there are no sudden jumps and to avoid problems due to network anomalies.

So when `ntpstat` says it's synchronize, it's about as close as it can get, but it gives it's best estimate of how far off it's likely to be.